# Conjunctions using stems, and its conjugation

Tags: conjunctions, written-language

While working through the Tobira textbook, I came to a grammar point Chapter 1 - #5. This stated verb stems and adverbial い-adj form could be used to combine sentences as in:

> 1. 昨日は友達とレストランで晩ご飯を**食べ**、その後、映画を見に行った。
> 2. この地方は冬は雪が**多く**、夏はとても暑い。

It doesn't give English translations but I take these sentences to mean:

> 1. Yesterday I ate dinner with my friend at a restaurant, and after that we went to go watch a movie.
> 2. In this region, the winters have a lot of snow and the summers are very hot.

My question is whether this grammar structure can only be used with non-conjugated phrases. This mostly concerns negative vs. affirmative sense, since the 1st example shows that the first phrase will have the same past/non-past sense as the following phrase.

For example, (following the pattern of い-adj --> て-form w/out て) do these make sense/sound idiomatic:

> 3. 姉は**高くなく**、まだ早くジョギングができます。
>
> *My sister is not tall, and still she can jog quickly*
>
> 4. 今日お昼ご飯を**食べなく**、4時よりおなかがペコペコになってしまいました。
>
> *Today I did not eat lunch, and from 4 o-clock on I became hungry*

If these do not make sense, is there a similar grammar structure to use? Or would just a word with the opposite sense be used instead?

Answer (score 1):

You're right. That's how you conjugate ない forms, and I find nothing wrong with the following examples that you provided:

> 3. 姉は**高くなく**、まだ早くジョギングができます。
>
> *My sister is not tall, and still she can jog quickly*
>
> 4. 今日お昼ご飯を**食べなく**、4時よりおなかがペコペコになってしまいました。
>
> *Today I did not eat lunch, and from 4 o-clock on I became hungry*

That being said, please do note that this form is more common in written Japanese than in spoken Japanese. As far as I know, patterns like い-adj --> て-form are more common in spoken Japanese.

To include Mindful's correction, the last option is better written as

> 4. 今日お昼ご飯を**食べないで**、4時よりおなかがペコペコになってしまいました。

Comment: My question wasn't so much "is my conjugation correct" but, does that conjugation work in the grammar structure, could you add info on that matter?

Comment: Done with the edits :)

Comment: Unfortunately there is something wrong with last example, purely because the negative for verbs in this case behaves unusually. See [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/40740/negative-te-form-vs-te-form-of-the-negative) and also [here](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/negativeverbs2).

Comment: @Mindful Thank you for your comment. Are you referring to the fact that it should not be 今日お昼ご飯を食べなくて4時より〜 but 今日お昼ご飯を食べないで4時より〜?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If you wanted to match the stiff and formal feeling of dropping て like in 高くなく then ず is also an option, but the simplest/most basic option for negation here is ないで.

Comment: I agree, I actually thought of using ず but it would be a bit too different in terms of form, plus I don't think ず is not taught in Tobira this early.