# What is the meaning of と in this sentence?

Tags: translation, particle-と, negation, imperatives

Its from the song "Stay with me";

> 帰らないでと泣いた

Also, is there a better way to translate the 'naide' form of a verb than "without doing"? It sounds quite odd I think.

Comment: got a link to the full lyrics?

Comment: http://j-lyric.net/artist/a000575/l03490c.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be the quoting `と`:

"Don't go!", [she] cried.

Or the the contidional one (though it's unlikely here , as mentioned by @snailplane below):

When [she] said "Don't go", [I] cried.

To tell which it is, we'd need more context.

---

**EDIT**

I found the lyrics (「真夜中のドア～Stay with me」 by 唐沢美帆) and the song  goes like this:

```
私は私　貴方は貴方と
昨夜言ってた　そんな気もするわ
グレイのジャケットに見覚えがある　コーヒーのしみ
相変わらずなのね
ショーウィンドウに二人映れば

Stay with me...
真夜中のドアをたたき　帰らないでと泣いた
あの季節が今　目の前
Stay with me
口癖を言いながら　二人の瞬間を抱いて
まだ忘れず　大事にしていた
```

So it seems the first version is correct, except the subject is the singer.

> I cried, pleading "Don't go!".

(changed slightly to avoid the double meaning of the English verb "cry")

The other stanzas also use the quoting `と` many times.

---

As for `～ないで`,  here it is short for `～ないで下さい`, i.e. it's a request to not do something (go back in this case). See also [Why don't we use ～なくて instead of ～ないで?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25246/)

Comment: The 接続助詞「と」 is supposed to follow a 活用語の終止形, so I don't think it would normally follow ～ないで, right?

Comment: @snailplane: yeah, the second version is probably wrong

Comment: Ahh, I mistook it for "without doing". Thanks for your help